# Alias: How can i send "alias" to background?

Tags: bash, alias

I would like to send alias with input parameters to a back

the alias:

```
alias aaa="/script.sh"
```

usage:

```
aaa input1 input2 inpu3
```

now i can send aaa to background by adding "&> /dev/null &" but adding this to an alias doesn't work because of the input

```
aaa input1 input2 inpu3 &> /dev/null &
```

what i have tried so far:

```
alias aaa="/script.sh &> /dev/null &"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write another script file with code below inside it and make alias for that.

script2.sh:

```
./script.sh "$@" > /dev/null &
```

Make alias:

```
alias aaa="./script2.sh"
```

Comment: No need for a separate script; use a function instead of an alias. Or just put the script itself in your `PATH` and call it `aaa`, and omit the alias.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that with an alias.
Make a function insted.

```
function aaa() {
   script.sh $@ &

}

aaa input1 input2 inpu3 > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just run it... Hit ctrl-z then type bg. This will run it in the background.

Comment: I was doing this, and I got lazy and googled for this SO thread.